# Converting redux to redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

React beginner here, learning by coding, need some help/advice to convert this Redux store to Redux toolkit, here i'm using function called configureStore, what is good way of changing this into using the 'configureStore'
which comes from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
this is for learning purpose
that 'createRootReducer' comes from my reducers.js which combines

```
const createRootReducer = (history) => combineReducers({
articles: articlesReducer,
selection: selectionReducer,
```

});

would appreciate any help/advice.
my store.js:

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { routerMiddleware } from "connected-react-router";
import createRootReducer from "./reducers";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const storeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  const store = createStore(
    createRootReducer(history),
    preloadedState,
    storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), thunk))
  );
  return store;
}
```

Comment: would apreciate any help

Comment: I have the same doubt cuz I'm also trying to migrate to toolkit, but the docs are not clear about how is the store wrapped over the `App` component. I'm at this moment thinking of using the same `store` setup but using the toolkit reducers and actions.